# how to create a multiple object value, if item is an arrary of arrays [[arr1],[arr2],[arr3,]

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures, ecmascript-6

I have an object like this:

```
const objects = {
  Battery: {
    batteryDetailsKey: ["serial_no", "type", "part_no"],
    batteryDetailsVal: ["HJ3CA19347410218LJ98 151 QC", "Extended Range", "4P94-Q051"],
  },
  Modules: {
    moduleDetailsKey: ["serial_no", "part_no", "cell_count"],
    moduleDetailsVal: ["8367532735006109322258160 50", "LJ98-10C779-A51", "32", "6"],
  },
};
```

I have written a function so that it becomes a key/val pair object

```
function twoArraysToObject(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.reduce((obj, item, index) => {
    obj[item] = arr2[index];
    return obj;
  }, {});
}

const desiredObject = {};
Object.keys(objects).forEach((key) => {
  const keyNamesArr = Object.keys(objects[key]);
  desiredObject[key] = twoArraysToObject(objects[key][keyNamesArr[0]], objects[key][keyNamesArr[1]]);
});
```

it does give me what i want with this data structure:

```
{
  "Battery": {
    "serial_no": "HJ3CA19347410218LJ98 151 QC",
    "type": "Extended Range",
    "part_no": "4P94-Q051"
  },
  "Modules": {
    "serial_no": "8367532735006109322258160 50",
    "part_no": "LJ98-10C779-A51",
    "cell_count": "32"
  }
}
```

However there's an issue in the code when moduleDetailsVal has multiple arrays rather than just 1 array with values:

```
const objects = {
  Battery: {
    batteryDetailsKey: ["serial_no", "type", "part_no"],
    batteryDetailsVal: ["HJ3CA19347410218LJ98 151 QC", "Extended Range", "4P94-Q051"],
  },
  Modules: {
    moduleDetailsKey: ["serial_no", "part_no", "cell_count"],
    moduleDetailsVal: [
        ["8367532735006109322258160 50", "LJ98-10C779-A51", "32", "6"],
        ["8367532735006109322258160 51", "LJ98-10C779-A52", "33", "6"],
        ["8367532735006109322258160 52", "LJ98-10C779-A52", "34", "6"],
    ]
  },
};
```

My code is only reading one moduleDetailsVal, but in reality it should read all of them, and there could be numerous amounts of Arrays inside moduleDetailsVal, not just 2 or 3

I ideally want it too look like this:

```
{
  "Battery": {
    "serial_no": "HJ3CA19347410218LJ98 151 QC",
    "type": "Extended Range",
    "part_no": "4P94-Q051"
  },
  "Modules": [
    {
      "serial_no": "8367532735006109322258160 50",
      "part_no": "LJ98-10C779-A51",
      "cell_count": "32"
    },
     {
      "serial_no": "8367532735006109322258160 51",
      "part_no": "LJ98-10C779-A52",
      "cell_count": "33"
    },
     {
      "serial_no": "8367532735006109322258160 52",
      "part_no": "LJ98-10C779-A53",
      "cell_count": "33"
    },

  ]
}
```

Adding my full code as @re-za's answer is not 100% working as expected.

```
const csvDataObjects = [
    {
        "Battery": {
            "batteryDetailsKey": [
                "Serial Number",
                "Type",
                "Part Number",
                "Length",
                "Width",
                "Height",
                "Weight",
                "Date Manufactured",
                "Manufacturer",
                "Capacity",
                "Design Capacity",
                "Capacity Percentage",
                "Temperature",
                "Cycle Count",
                "Recharge Level Percentage",
                "Wear Level Percentage",
                "Date Taken on",
                "Bill of Materials",
                "Bill of Landing",
                "Safety Sheet",
                "Asset Status"
            ],
            "batteryDetailsVal": [
                "HJ3CA19347410218LJ98 151 QC",
                "Extended Range",
                "4P94-Q051",
                "40",
                "68",
                "11",
                "600",
                "15 January 2021",
                "Ford Motor Company",
                "68",
                "88",
                "100",
                "68",
                "0",
                "100",
                "0",
                "3 March 2021",
                "bill_of_materials_for_this_battery.pdf",
                "bill_of_lading_for_this_battery.pdf",
                "safety_sheet_for_this_type.pdf",
                "End of life"
            ]
        },
        "Modules": {
            "moduleDetailsKey": [
                "Serial Number",
                "Part Number",
                "Cell Count",
                "Length",
                "Width",
                "Height",
                "Weight",
                "Date Manufactured",
                "Manufacturer",
                "Short Form Name",
                "Chemical Full Name",
                "Formula",
                "Cobalt Percentage",
                "Nickel Content",
                "Lithium Content",
                "Cobalt Content",
                "Attached To Battery",
                "Asset Status",
                "",
                "",
                ""
            ],
            "moduleDetailsVal": [
                "8367532735006109322258160 50",
                "LJ98-10C779-A51",
                "32",
                "6",
                "19",
                "4",
                "35",
                "16 December 2020",
                "LG Chem",
                "NCM-111",
                "Lithium Nickel Manganese Cobalt Oxide",
                "LiNiMnCoO",
                "33",
                "56",
                "50",
                "54",
                "true",
                "End of life",
                "",
                "",
                ""
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "Battery": {
            "batteryDetailsKey": [
                "Serial Number",
                "Type",
                "Part Number",
                "Length",
                "Width",
                "Height",
                "Weight",
                "Date Manufactured",
                "Manufacturer",
                "Capacity",
                "Design Capacity",
                "Capacity Percentage",
                "Temperature",
                "Cycle Count",
                "Recharge Level Percentage",
                "Wear Level Percentage",
                "Date Taken on",
                "Bill of Materials",
                "Bill of Landing",
                "Safety Sheet",
                "Asset Status"
            ],
            "batteryDetailsVal": [
                "HJ3CA19347410218LJ98 152 QC",
                "Extended Range",
                "4P94-Q052",
                "50",
                "77",
                "12",
                "680",
                "6 June 2020",
                "Ford Motor Company",
                "71",
                "73",
                "96",
                "67",
                "0",
                "98",
                "2",
                "3 July 2020",
                "bill_of_materials_for_this_battery_2.pdf",
                "bill_of_lading_for_this_battery_2.pdf",
                "safety_sheet_for_this_type_2.pdf",
                "End of life"
            ]
        },
        "Modules": {
            "moduleDetailsKey": [
                "Serial Number",
                "Part Number",
                "Cell Count",
                "Length",
                "Width",
                "Height",
                "Weight",
                "Date Manufactured",
                "Manufacturer",
                "Short Form Name",
                "Chemical Full Name",
                "Formula",
                "Cobalt Percentage",
                "Nickel Content",
                "Lithium Content",
                "Cobalt Content",
                "Attached To Battery",
                "Asset Status",
                "",
                "",
                ""
            ],
            "moduleDetailsVal": [
                [
                    "8367532735006109322258160 51",
                    "LJ98-10C779-A52",
                    "28",
                    "10",
                    "22",
                    "5",
                    "42",
                    "7 April 2020",
                    "LG Chem",
                    "NCM-111",
                    "Lithium Nickel Manganese Cobalt Oxide",
                    "LiNiMnCoO",
                    "31",
                    "59",
                    "44",
                    "60",
                    "true",
                    "End of life",
                    "",
                    "",
                    ""
                ],
                [
                    "8367532735006109322258161 52",
                    "LJ98-10C779-A53",
                    "27",
                    "11",
                    "20",
                    "6",
                    "43",
                    "7 April 2020",
                    "LG Chem",
                    "NCM-111",
                    "Lithium Nickel Manganese Cobalt Oxide",
                    "LiNiMnCoO",
                    "31",
                    "59",
                    "44",
                    "60",
                    "true",
                    "End of life",
                    "",
                    "",
                    ""
                ]
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "Battery": {
            "batteryDetailsKey": [
                "Serial Number",
                "Type",
                "Part Number",
                "Length",
                "Width",
                "Height",
                "Weight",
                "Date Manufactured",
                "Manufacturer",
                "Capacity",
                "Design Capacity",
                "Capacity Percentage",
                "Temperature",
                "Cycle Count",
                "Recharge Level Percentage",
                "Wear Level Percentage",
                "Date Taken on",
                "Bill of Materials",
                "Bill of Landing",
                "Safety Sheet",
                "Asset Status"
            ],
            "batteryDetailsVal": [
                "HJ3CA19347410218LJ98 153 QC",
                "Extended Range",
                "4P94-Q053",
                "50",
                "77",
                "12",
                "680",
                "6 June 2020",
                "Ford Motor Company",
                "71",
                "73",
                "96",
                "67",
                "0",
                "98",
                "2",
                "3 July 2020",
                "bill_of_materials_for_this_battery_2.pdf",
                "bill_of_lading_for_this_battery_2.pdf",
                "safety_sheet_for_this_type_2.pdf",
                "End of life"
            ]
        },
        "Modules": {
            "moduleDetailsKey": [
                "Serial Number",
                "Part Number",
                "Cell Count",
                "Length",
                "Width",
                "Height",
                "Weight",
                "Date Manufactured",
                "Manufacturer",
                "Short Form Name",
                "Chemical Full Name",
                "Formula",
                "Cobalt Percentage",
                "Nickel Content",
                "Lithium Content",
                "Cobalt Content",
                "Attached To Battery",
                "Asset Status",
                "",
                "",
                ""
            ],
            "moduleDetailsVal": [
                [
                    "8367532735006109322258162 53",
                    "LJ98-10C779-A54",
                    "28",
                    "10",
                    "22",
                    "5",
                    "42",
                    "7 April 2020",
                    "LG Chem",
                    "NCM-111",
                    "Lithium Nickel Manganese Cobalt Oxide",
                    "LiNiMnCoO",
                    "31",
                    "59",
                    "44",
                    "60",
                    "true",
                    "End of life",
                    "",
                    "",
                    ""
                ],
                [
                    "8367532735006109322258163 54",
                    "LJ98-10C779-A55",
                    "27",
                    "11",
                    "20",
                    "6",
                    "43",
                    "7 April 2020",
                    "LG Chem",
                    "NCM-111",
                    "Lithium Nickel Manganese Cobalt Oxide",
                    "LiNiMnCoO",
                    "31",
                    "59",
                    "44",
                    "60",
                    "true",
                    "End of life",
                    "",
                    "",
                    ""
                ],
                [
                    "8367532735006109322258163 56",
                    "LJ98-10C779-A56",
                    "27",
                    "11",
                    "20",
                    "6",
                    "43",
                    "7 April 2020",
                    "LG Chem",
                    "NCM-111",
                    "Lithium Nickel Manganese Cobalt Oxide",
                    "LiNiMnCoO",
                    "31",
                    "59",
                    "44",
                    "60",
                    "true",
                    "End of life",
                    "",
                    "",
                    ""
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
]
    
const mappedObjects = csvDataObjects.map((csvObj) => {
    function twoArraysToObject(arr1, arr2) {
      return arr1.reduce((obj, item, index) => {
        obj[item] = Array.isArray(arr2[index])
          ? arr2.map((a) => a[index])
          : arr2[index]
        return obj;
      }, {});
    }
    const desiredObject = {};

    Object.keys(csvObj).forEach((key) => {
      const keyNamesArr = Object.keys(csvObj[key]);
      desiredObject[key] = twoArraysToObject(csvObj[key][keyNamesArr[0]], csvObj[key][keyNamesArr[1]]);
    });

    Object.keys(desiredObject).forEach(key => {
      if (desiredObject[key] === '') {
        delete desiredObject[key];
      }
    });
    

    return desiredObject
  });
console.log(mappedObjects)
```

Comment: So it can sometimes be one array and sometime an array of array?

Comment: yep, so it can be 
moduleDetailsVal: [1,2,3]

or

moduleDetailsVal: [[1,2,3], [1,2,3]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the reduce, change

```
obj[item] = arr2[index];
```

to:

```
obj[item] = Array.isArray(arr2[0])
      ? arr2.map(a => a[index])
      : arr2[index]
```

So you'll have:

```
function twoArraysToObject(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.reduce((obj, item, index) => {
    if (item === "") return obj
    
    obj[item] = Array.isArray(arr2[0])
      ? arr2.map(a => a[index])
      : arr2[index]
    return obj;
  }, {});
}
```

**Working Example**

```js
const csvDataObjects = [
  {
    "Battery": {
      "batteryDetailsKey": ["Serial Number", "Type", "Part Number"],
      "batteryDetailsVal": ["HJ3CA19347410218LJ98 152 QC", "Extended Range", "4P94-Q052"]
    },
    "Modules": {
      "moduleDetailsKey": ["Serial Number", "Part Number", "Cell Count", ""],
      "moduleDetailsVal": [
        ["8367532735006109322258160 51", "LJ98-10C779-A52", "28", ""],
        ["8367532735006109322258161 52", "LJ98-10C779-A53", "27", ""]
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "Battery": {
      "batteryDetailsKey": ["Serial Number", "Type", "Part Number"],
      "batteryDetailsVal": ["HJ3CA19347410218LJ98 153 QC", "Extended Range", "4P94-Q053"]
    },
    "Modules": {
      "moduleDetailsKey": ["Serial Number", "Part Number", "Cell Count", ""],
      "moduleDetailsVal": [
        ["8367532735006109322258162 53", "LJ98-10C779-A54", "28", ""],
        ["8367532735006109322258163 54", "LJ98-10C779-A55", "27", ""],
        ["8367532735006109322258163 56", "LJ98-10C779-A56", "27", ""]
      ]
    }
  }
]



function twoArraysToObject(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.reduce((obj, item, index) => {
    if (item === "") return obj

    obj[item] = (Array.isArray(arr2[0]))
      ? arr2.map((a) => a[index])
      : obj[item] = arr2[index]

    return obj;
  }, {});
}



const mappedObjects = csvDataObjects.map((csvObj) => {
  const desiredObject = {};
  Object.keys(csvObj).forEach((key) => {
    const keyNamesArr = Object.keys(csvObj[key]);
    desiredObject[key] = twoArraysToObject(csvObj[key][keyNamesArr[0]], csvObj[key][keyNamesArr[1]]);
  });
  return desiredObject
});


console.log(mappedObjects)
```

It works both for cases: array and array of arrays.

Comment: @Jim41Mavs Let me know if this answer help you.

Comment: it's not working, well it works for when moduleDetailsVal is a single array, but when it becomes an array of arrays it doesn't work

Comment: @Jim41Mavs weird! it's working on my side! with your own example. let me create a working example here

Comment: @Jim41Mavs see working example, using your own example data. It's working both for Battery (array) and Modules (array of array)

Comment: I just edited my question and added in the full code. Basically i'm implementing your function within an iteration. I can't see why it doesn't work properly. The Modules object has the correct object keys, but all of the values are undefined except for part number and serial number

Comment: @Jim41Mavs I found the bug. as per the edited answer replace `Array.isArray(arr2[index])` with `Array.isArray(arr2[0])`. Here we shouldn't have put index, we just want to check if arr2 is an array of array so checking if it's first element is an array is enough

Comment: you are a genius! thanks for spotting that bug, and thanks for all the other comments with coding help/advice. Appreciate it greatly! I might actually be able to hit my deadline for this project :P 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243254/discussion-between-re-za-and-jim41mavs).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in a very simple way by using `Array.map()` and `.forEach()` method **:**

```js
const modules = {
  moduleDetailsKey: ["serial_no", "part_no", "cell_count"],
  moduleDetailsVal: [
    ["8367532735006109322258160 50", "LJ98-10C779-A51", "32", "6"],
    ["8367532735006109322258160 51", "LJ98-10C779-A52", "33", "6"],
    ["8367532735006109322258160 52", "LJ98-10C779-A52", "34", "6"],
  ]
};

const res = modules.moduleDetailsVal.map((arr) => {
  const obj = {};
    modules.moduleDetailsKey.forEach((key, index) => {
        obj[key] = arr[index]
    });
  return obj;
});

console.log(res);
```

Just for Demo purpose, I worked on `modules` array so that it will give you the way how to achieve it.